# Instead of Trigger para inserir valores - ORACLE

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, tabela-banco-de-dados, trigger, sqldeveloper

Resumindo meu problema, eu preciso inserir valores automaticamente em uma tabela após outros valores serem inseridos na mesma. A forma que eu encontrei de fazer isso no Oracle foi utilizando uma **trigger** do tipo **INSTEAD OF**. Entretanto, após implementar e testar a **trigger**, nenhum valor foi inserido.

Montei um pequeno caso de teste no site **dbfiddle**, alguém poderia me ajudar e me explicar o que exatamente impede que eu faça meus **inserts**?.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=262e83082d65b69aa8d851ac09b35795

Código que usei para teste:

```
create table timdtl(dtlcodigo number, dtldescricao varchar(20));

create view dtl_view as select * from timdtl;

create or replace trigger gera_detalhamento
    instead of insert on dtl_view
    for each row
begin

    insert into timdtl values(1, 'Trigger Test');

end;
/

insert into timdtl
values(666, 'Manual Insert');
```

Resultado Esperado: 666 | Manual Insert
                    1   | Trigger Test

Resultado Obtido: 666 | Manual Insert

Obs: Estou usando essa trigger em específico para evitar o erro de tabela mutante que ocorre quando tento inserir valores na mesma tabela que está sendo atualizada.

Comment: Nunca usei isto mas creio que o insert tem de ser na view. "No lugar de" inserir a trigger será chamada. Mas não entendi o problema original.

Comment: O problema original é um pouco mais complexo e longo para colocar todo aqui, isso resolveria parte dele. Mesmo eu colocando o insert na view o resultado permanece o mesmo

Comment: Veja isto , parecido com seu caso creio. https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-instead-of-triggers/

Comment: Eu estou exatamente com esse link aberto para entender melhor, mas ainda assim não consegui resolver meu problema